# Add others fields to a new DataList instead the Title in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Please I need to know, when at the beginning, the user creates a new DataList from web interface :

- how to delete default Alfresco Datalist for example "Elenco di contatti" or "Elenco di eventi" ecc..... in order to see only my custom Datalist to choose
- how to delete "Descrizione" and "Titolo" field and how to add others/my mandatory fields to a Datalist creation

[see the image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEv7G.png)

I did exactly as Muralidharan told me in the response but :

when from interface I create a datalist the Title is not disappeared

and also when I try to modify the datalist show up the Title again and also Description and I don't want them

[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEv7G.png)

How to adjust it ?

this is the code of datalist-model.xml

```
    <types>
<type name="acmedl:dataList">
         <title>Data List container type</title>
         <parent>cm:folder</parent>
         <properties>
            <property name="dl:dataListItemType">
               <title>List Item Type</title>
               <description>Determines which Data Dictionary type will be used when create new items within the Data List.</description>
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="dl:responsiblePerson">
               <title>Data List Owner</title>               
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
         </properties>
        </type>

        <type name="acmedl:projectListItem">
            <title>My document</title>
            <parent>dl:dataListItem</parent>
            <properties>
                <property name="acmedl:x1">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint ref="acmedl:x1" />
                    </constraints>
                </property>
                <property name="acmedl:x2">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                </property>
                <property name="acmedl:x3">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </type>
    </types>
```

this is the code of share-config-custom.xml

```
<!-- dl:dataList type (Creating Data Lists) -->
   <config evaluator="model-type" condition="acmedl:dataList" replace="true">
      <forms>
         <!-- Data Lists: Create new Data List -->
         <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <!-- <show id="cm:title" force="true" /> -->
               <show id="dl:responsiblePerson" force="true" />        <!-- Our custom field -->        
            </field-visibility>
            <create-form template="../data-lists/forms/datalist-new.ftl" />
            <appearance>
             <!-- <field id="cm:title" mandatory="true">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
               </field> -->
               <field id="dl:responsiblePerson" mandatory="true">  <!-- Our custom field -->
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
               </field>
            </appearance>
         </form>
      </forms>
   </config>

   <!-- dl:dataList type (Editing Data Lists) -->
   <config evaluator="node-type" condition="acmedl:dataList">
      <forms>
         <!-- Data Lists: Edit Data List details -->
         <form>
            <field-visibility>
                 <!-- <show id="cm:title" force="true" /> -->
                <show id="dl:responsiblePerson" force="true" />     <!-- Our custom field -->
            </field-visibility>
            <edit-form template="../data-lists/forms/datalist-edit.ftl" />
            <appearance>
              <!-- <field id="cm:title" mandatory="true">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
               </field> -->
               <field id="dl:responsiblePerson" mandatory="true"> <!-- Our custom field -->
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
               </field>

            </appearance>
         </form>
      </forms>
   </config>



    <!--
        acmedl:projectListItem type create form config
        -->
    <config evaluator="model-type" condition="acmedl:projectListItem">
        <forms>
            <!-- Create item form -->
            <form>
                <field-visibility>
                    <show id="acmedl:x1" />
                    <show id="acmedl:x2" />
                    <show id="acmedl:x3" />
                </field-visibility>
                <create-form template="../data-lists/forms/dataitem.ftl" />
                <appearance>
                </appearance>
            </form>
        </forms>
    </config>

    <!--
        acmedl:projectListItem type edit form config
    -->
    <config evaluator="node-type" condition="acmedl:projectListItem">
        <forms>
            <form>
                <field-visibility>
                    <show id="acmedl:x1" />
                    <show id="acmedl:x2" />
                    <show id="acmedl:x3" />
                </field-visibility>
                <edit-form template="../data-lists/forms/dataitem.ftl" />
                <appearance>
                </appearance>
            </form>
        </forms>
    </config>
```

Comment: Read this: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/references/dev-extension-points-data-lists.html

Comment: this is exactly what I already did

Answer (score 2):

After looking at this code, dataList is inherited from cm:folder. If you want to add any custom properties, first those properties should be part of dl:dataList, otherwise, you can't store the values into Repository. And I'm also not sure, how to custom properties into existing dataList. Let me ask this as a different question.

```
<!-- Data List - Container. DO NOT MODIFY -->
      <type name="dl:dataList">
         <title>Data List container type</title>
         <parent>cm:folder</parent>
         <properties>
            <property name="dl:dataListItemType">
               <title>List Item Type</title>
               <description>Determines which Data Dictionary type will be used when create new items within the Data List.</description>
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
         </properties>
      </type>
```

I added one few field called, *Data List Owner (dl:responsiblePerson)* into datalist model and Share side also.  Based on this idea, I hope you can addd your own fields.

We assume, we manually added a custom property(*dl:responsiblePerson*) into dl:dataList, like below.

```
<type name="dl:dataList">
         <title>Data List container type</title>
         <parent>cm:folder</parent>
         <properties>
            <property name="dl:dataListItemType">
               <title>List Item Type</title>
               <description>Determines which Data Dictionary type will be used when create new items within the Data List.</description>
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="dl:responsiblePerson">
               <title>Data List Owner</title>               
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
         </properties>
      </type>
```

And in Share side, use the below code snippet into share-config-custom.xml file.
Always use cm:title property in the datalist creation form, otherwise you getting datalist name some alpha-number / GUID value.

```
<!-- dl:dataList type (Creating Data Lists) -->
   <config evaluator="model-type" condition="dl:dataList" replace="true">
      <forms>
         <!-- Data Lists: Create new Data List -->
         <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="cm:title" force="true" />
               <show id="dl:responsiblePerson" force="true" />        <!-- Our custom field -->        
            </field-visibility>
            <create-form template="../data-lists/forms/datalist-new.ftl" />
            <appearance>
             <field id="cm:title" mandatory="true">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
               </field>
               <field id="dl:responsiblePerson" mandatory="true">  <!-- Our custom field -->
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
               </field>
            </appearance>
         </form>
      </forms>
   </config>

   <!-- dl:dataList type (Editing Data Lists) -->
   <config evaluator="node-type" condition="dl:dataList">
      <forms>
         <!-- Data Lists: Edit Data List details -->
         <form>
            <field-visibility>
                 <show id="cm:title" force="true" />
                <show id="dl:responsiblePerson" force="true" />     <!-- Our custom field -->
            </field-visibility>
            <edit-form template="../data-lists/forms/datalist-edit.ftl" />
            <appearance>
              <field id="cm:title" mandatory="true">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
               </field>
               <field id="dl:responsiblePerson" mandatory="true"> <!-- Our custom field -->
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" />
               </field>

            </appearance>
         </form>
      </forms>
   </config>
```

[image: Data List Creation]

Comment: Hy ! Thanks a lot. I feel sorry because for now I have a schedule change from my client and before I have to use my time to develop Alfresco, Ldap amd Smart Card. I will let you know later on about your DataList example and if works for me :-)

Comment: Muralidharan I updated my question for you, please check out

Comment: Have you modified the datalist.xml model file?

Comment: Yes sure, infact I see the 'Data List Owner' field

Comment: Have you updated share-config-custom.xml file, to ignore (remove) the description field? You can't remove the title field, as it is used for the datalist name. Please share your ideas / comments.